# Use of needn't in sentences

Tags: grammar, british-english

Are the sentences below correct?

Which is more commonly used in BrE? Do you use them both?

Need without "to", are they possible?

I need go to the hospital to get the special treatments.

I needn't go to the hospital to get the special treatments.

Need I go to the hospital to get the special treatments?

Needn't I go to the hospital to get the special treatments?

I've ever heard that "need" with "to" can be used in all verbs, and "need" without "to" Only can be used in the present, if you want to put "need" without "to", I must put "have" after the "need" e.g. I needn't/ need have gone.

Are the facts correct, I await for your explanations, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The question is confusing, here are the sentences:

I **need go** to the hospital to get the special treatments. [no]

Correction: I need **to go to the hospital to** get special treatments. [corrected]

I **needn't go** to the hospital to get the special treatments. [correct]

**Need I go** to the hospital to get the special treatments? [yes]  More common usage is: Do I need to go or Have I got to go.

Needn't I go to the hospital to get the special treatments? [yes].

**Needn't I go** means: Do I not have to go? Have I not got to go?. What is often actually said also is: Haven't I got to go etc.?

Comment: Need is used as modal verbs too. The modal form of "need" normally refers to 'immediate necessity'; usually negative as “needn't”. “don’t need” or in the case of ‘he/she’ “doesn’t need” [as the ordinary form] refers to general necessity.
Compare:
You needn’t fill in this form. {You don't have to do this now.}
You don’t need to pay for a form. {Generally it is not necessary}

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqii immediate necessity: I need to go right now. [**not a modal, and not negative**. need to go=have to go, have got to go; AKA must go]. Negative of this non-modal: I don't need to go right now. And that's enough on this for now. Need in these examples I just gave is the **main verb**.